# Django template doesn't display the model items

Tags: python, html, django

sorry, I'm very new as a member (and as developer too). I've recently started to work with Django, and I'm trying to display on a page, a list of articles with some elements (title, image, created_at, content), already done in a model.

The views, the template and the path (urls) were  bilt too. But when I Run the server and open the browser it only displays the title I passed as the render parameter in the view, not the object (articles = Article.objects.all()), created in the view.

blog/models.py

```
from email.mime import image
from email.policy import default
from tabnanny import verbose
from turtle import update
from unicodedata import category
from venv import create
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='name')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='description')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created_at')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural= 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="title")
    content= RichTextField(verbose_name='Content')
    image= models.ImageField(default='null', verbose_name="Image")
    public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Public?")
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User", on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Category',  blank=True)
    create_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    update_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="update at")
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article'
        verbose_name_plural= 'Articles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Article, Category

# Create your views here.

def list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {
         'title' : 'Articles',
         'articles': articles
      } )
```

blog/list.html

```
  {% extends 'layouts/layout.html' %}
    
    {% block title  %}
        {{title}}
    {% endblock  %}
    {% block content  %}
        <h1 class= "title">{{title}}</h1>
        {% for article in articles %} 
                <article class="article-item">                
                    {% if article.image != 'null' and article.image|length >= 1 %}
                        <div class="image ">
                            <img src="{{article.image.url}}" />
                        </div>                                  
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="data"> 
                        <h2>
                            {{article.title}}
                        </h2>                    
                        <span class="date">{{article.create_at}}</span>                         
                         <p>{{article.content|safe}} </p>
                    </div>              
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </article>
        {%endfor%}

     {% endblock  %}
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: You didn't include `models`, you have pasted `views` twice :)

Comment: already changed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the whole block content is not rendered - Do you have a {% block content %} in the layout.html? You can check in your browser if the source code contains the html of the content block and just the tags are missing

Comment: yes, it is located in the main app (MainApp/templates/layouts/layout.html). and I'm working at  another app (blog/templates/articles/list.html)

Comment: You should always use a structure like app/templates/app/xxx.html. Do you see the html code in content rendered?

Comment: Add a print(articels) in the view to check if there is data in the query

Comment: I added the print in the title (cuz is the only one displayed in the page), as value   'title': print(articles)  and as result: None. is it right, where else can I added to check ?

Comment: did you add some items to Articles? if not, the database table is empty and in your view articles = Article.objects.all() will return nothing

Comment: I already know what happened. Forgot to register my models at the admin.py. problem solved. thanks anyway